# Qual a diferença entre a complexidade de um algoritmo e a complexidade de um problema?

Tags: complexidade-de-algoritmo, teoria-da-computação

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre a complexidade de um algoritmo e a complexidade de um problema, ou seja, quais os pontos que diferem as duas coisas

Comment: Te aconselho a dar uma olhada na resposta desta pergunta : https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13669/what-is-the-difference-between-an-algorithm-a-language-and-a-problem e também olhar este pdf : https://www.ime.usp.br/~song/mac5710/slides/01complex.pdf

Comment: Normalmente, complexidade de software normalmente tem a ver com o que o software faz, quantidade de responsabilidades, coisas assim. Veja a [Lei de Zawinski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zawinski's_law_of_software_envelopment?wprov=sfsi1)

Answer (score 0):

A terminologia correta é dizer que um problema *pertence* a uma *classe* de complexidade temporal.

Para saber a qual classe um problema pertence, devemos ver qual é o melhor algoritmo que resolve aquele problema (isto é, o algoritmo com a menor complexidade temporal):

- Se este algoritmo tiver complexidade polinomial, o problema pertence à classe P;
- Se este algoritmo tiver complexidade exponencial, o problema pertence à classe EXPTIME;
- etc